# Getting "MojoExecutionException"

Tags: maven, exception, pom.xml, maven-plugin

`Hi,

When I was trying to run a test in different environment using **mvn clean install -Dev="qa"**
I was getting **BUILD FAILURE,** **MojoExecutionException**

[console output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1BQT.png)

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Nov2022POMSeries</groupId>
    <artifactId>Nov2022POMSeries</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <extentreports-version>5.0.8</extentreports-version>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.19</aspectj.version>
        <allure.version>2.22.1</allure.version>

    </properties>

<!--    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://admin:admin123@localhost:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement> -->

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>openxml4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>${extentreports-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>

                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>3</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testrunners/testng_regression.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        <!-- <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile> -->
                    </suiteXmlFiles>

                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>

                </configuration>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

            </plugin>
            



<!--            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>

                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin> -->


        </plugins>
    </build>

<reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportVersion>${allure.version}</reportVersion>
        <resultsDirectory>${project.basedir}/allure-results</resultsDirectory>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>


</project>
```

- Tried out with different dependency versions, but couldn't get the result.
- From **window > preference > java > installed jre > pointing to jdk**. It's also not working.`

Comment: First the whole stack (all dependencies etc.) are ancient old (poi etc. )...also the error message states that you are using somewhere Lombok which is not working with the JDK 17 you have configured ...

Comment: I don't think I am using Lombok anywhere in my project. But I have added Lombok dependency. Now it's working fine.